Is it possible to make the musical notes of an audio file in the piano roll to last the length of the notes and not of the audio file?
Suppose I have an audio file which lasts 2 seconds. But inside the piano roll I want to write musical notes which last 1 second or 0.5 seconds. Every time I write a musical note or press the key in the piano roll, the sound will last 2 seconds (the length of the audio file) and not the length of the musical notes I'm writing or pressing.
Is it possible to make the musical notes of an audio file in the piano roll to last the length of the notes and not of the audio file?

(Translation of this for those who are as confused as I was initially: "I'm working with a sample that lasts 2 seconds, and I want to be able to clip its playback to less than that.")

Your sample player should be able to respond to a note off command as well as a note on command. The note on command starts the sample, the note off should end it. In your case, the note off is ignored. We can't tell you why without more information about your setup.

@AndyBonner well done!  I couldn't make sense of it.

Again, assuming you are using the FL studio sampler:
Sound does not stop when the note is released because you have not set any volume envelope.
The second paragraph from the manual reads:
"ADSR & Filtering - Channel Samplers have a number of useful controls under the Channel Settings Tab controls that include the integrated ADSR vol, pan, filter, pitch & LFO envelopes. For example, samples will continue to play after note release unless you activate the Volume envelope."
https://www.image-line.com/fl-studio-learning/fl-studio-online-manual/html/chansettings_sampler.htm
